# ObjectOutputStream not sending data

Tags: java, sockets, networking, stream, objectoutputstream

Client code:

```
try {
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(input);
            out.writeByte(1);
            FileHandler fh = (FileHandler) in.readObject();
            //processing stuff
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Server code:

```
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(input);
            int type = in.readByte();
            //processing stuff (which includes closing the streams and sending FileHandler object)
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The server never receives the byte. It just waits for the byte from the client, and it never comes. I'm not sure why it isn't sending, or getting received. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to make a guess it's because in your client you block on `in.readObject();` waiting for the server to send you something thus never flush the output stream thus ... nothing ever gets sent.

Move your read to *after* you flush your output stream.

Comment: Also don't flush or close output.  If you wrap an OutputStream calling close or flush or close on it will in turn flush the contained stream.  You don't need to save a reference to output or input.  Close should also be placed in a finally clause should an exception be thrown you still need to make sure close() of streams occurs.

Comment: When I flush after sending the byte, the server gets a connection reset error.

Comment: @JonMannerberg - no, it gets that when you *close* the connection. Don't close it until you're done reading and writing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the writeObject and readObject methods. Also write an Integer not an int to the stream. Read [this really good lecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) before proceeding any further.

[This is also a good lecture](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) for your problem.

Regards!